# Prove Brownian Bridge is Sampling Without Replacement

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion, weak-convergence

Let's say we have a bowl containing $n$ many $+1$'s and $n$ many $-1$'s. You sample numbers from the bowl randomly without replacing. Let $k_1^{(n)}, k_2^{(n)}, ..., k_{2n}^{(n)}$ denote the random sequence of numbers from the process of sampling.

Let the partial sum process:
$$S_0=0 \; , \; S_a=\sum_{i=1}^a k_i^{(n)} \; , \; 1\leq a\leq 2n$$ We can define a sequence of continuous processes by scaling time and space via Donsker's theorem

$$X_{\frac{a}{2n}}^{(n)} = \frac{S_a}{\sqrt{n}} \; , \; a=0,1,2,...,2n$$

by linearly interpolating we get

$$X_{t}^{(n)} = X^{(n)}_{\frac{\lfloor 2nt\rfloor}{n}} + \frac{nt-\lfloor nt\rfloor}{\sqrt{n}} k_{\lfloor 2nt\rfloor+1}^{(n)} \; , \; 0 \leq t\leq1$$

How can we prove that the process $X^{(n)}$ converges weakly to a constant multiple of the standard Brownian bridge?

Comment: Any individual configuration of $(S_a)_{a \leq 2n}$ has probability $\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$, same as a simple random walk conditioned to end at $0$ after $2n$ steps. But after this I don't know what to do...

Comment: Now sure if you are allowed to use some advanced results, but notice that $(S_j : 0\leq j \leq 2n)$ has the same distribution as $(\tilde{S}_j : 0\leq j \leq 2n)$ conditioned to $\tilde{S}_{2n} = 0$, where $\tilde{S}$ is a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. So you can apply the invariance principle for Brownian bridge. (For instance, check [*this paper*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24901780).)

Answer (score 1):

I had this question too and wanted to share my attempt at a sketch of a proof. Despite falling short in both areas of completeness and rigor, I hope it moves in a generally correct direction; hopefully someone with greater prowess is willing to help me fill in the missing bits! (On that note, if this doesn't rise to the [guidelines set forth for answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), I'll gladly remove or change to a comment.)

The goal is to use the formulation of the Brownian Bridge as the unique Gaussian process $X_t, t\in[0, 1]$ with $\mathop{\mathbf{E}}X_t=0$ and $\mathbf{Cov}[X_s,X_t] = \min(s,t)(1-max(s,t))$.

Note first that in the above for fixed $n$, the $k_i$ are identical but *not* independent two-point random variables with $\mathbf{P}(k_i=1)=\mathbf{P}(k_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\mathop{\mathbf{E}}k_i=0,\mathop{\mathbf{Var}}k_i=1$ and covariance:

$$\mathbf{Cov}[k_i,k_j]=\mathop{\mathbf{E}}k_ik_j=\frac{n-1}{2n-1}-\frac{n}{2n-1}=-\frac{1}{2n-1}$$

Redefining the scaled process to be $X_\frac{a}{2n}^{(n)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}S_a$, from linearity of the expectation we immediately have:
$$\mathop{\mathbf{E}}X_\frac{a}{2n}^{(n)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\mathop{\mathbf{E}}\sum_{i=1}^{a}k_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\sum_{i=1}^{a}\mathop{\mathbf{E}}k_i=0$$

As for the covariance, letting $a\leq b$ without loss of generality:
$$\mathbf{Cov}\left[X_\frac{a}{2n}^{(n)},X_\frac{b}{2n}^{(n)}\right]=\frac{1}{2n}\mathop{\mathbf{E}}\sum_{i=1}^{a}k_i\sum_{j=1}^{b}k_j=\frac{1}{2n}\left(a(1)-a(b-1)\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=\frac{a}{2n}\left(1-\frac{b-1}{2n-1}\right)$$

We thus obtain the desired mean and covariances for the process $X_t$ by passing to the limit, if we are allowed to do so.

It also remains to be shown that the $X_t$ is Gaussian, which would follow from a suitable central limit theorem, if one exists! Note here that the $k_i^{(n)}$ are "asymptotically independent" in the sense that $\mathbf{P}(k_i^{(n)}=x|k_j^{(n)}=y) = \frac{n-\mathbb{1}(x=y)}{2n-1}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Whether that's sufficient for a central limit theorem I unfortunately couldn't find an answer for, but I'll keep poking around! (Note that even pure uncorrelatedness is not sufficient, [e.g. this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730696/central-limit-theorem-for-dependent-random-variables-with-covariance-condition))